# how to get deleted contact_groups from Google People API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-people-api

We use people api to get a list of contact_groups.
Although we use sync_token, we cannot get deleted groups. But people list do not have this problem. How to solve?

`service = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::PeopleServiceService.new
service.client_options.application_name = 'xxx' 
service.authorization=Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(credentials)
response = service.list_contact_groups(sync_token: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx)`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: service = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::PeopleServiceService.new
service.client_options.application_name = 'xxx'
service.authorization=Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(credentials)
response = service.list_contact_groups(sync_token: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx)

can't pull deleted groups.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, since it makes it really difficult to read. Instead, go ahead and update your original question (as @DaimTo has done for you) and make a note in the comments that you've done so. This makes it easier for all of us.

Comment: ok. thanks for your response

Comment: tried it [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/list), we are able to get information from a group that exists, but couldn't get deleted groups.

Answer (score 0):

[Contactgroups.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/list) returns a list of [contact groups](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups#ContactGroup) a contact group contains a [Contact group metadata](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups#ContactGroupMetadata) which contains a deleted paramater.

> True if the contact group resource has been deleted. Populated only for contactGroups.list requests that include a sync token.

I am not 100% sure i understand your question.

**Search only deleted**

There is no way to search only on deleted groups.  You are going to have to cache the full contactgroups.list method and scan the data locally.

**Data not returned**

If you are not seeing the deleted groups and you are 100% sure that this user has access to this information.   Then i would suggest that this information is not available via the api it is a common issue that not all of the fields in Google apis are publicly available to third party developers like us.  If this is the case then i suggest that you post an issue on the forum [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:344199%2B) that the information should be populated.

Comment: We synchronize contacts in our system with Google contacts. How do I know if a group is deleted? To delete my own people. It doesn't make sense to check all the groups every time. For example, [people_connections_list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) returns deleted contacts as deleted.

 [says here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups): **deleted** true if the contact group resource has been deleted. Populated only for contactGroups.list requests that include a sync token.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to search on deleted.   You are going to have to search it locally

Comment: okay. What does do **deleted** in [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups)? can you explain please ?

Comment: That file tells you if the content group has been deleted.

Comment: but not working :/ What I want to do is already. When the group is deleted, **deleted** field return **true**

Comment: If the group is deleted i would expect it to return true that the group is deleted.  That's kind of how a Boolean fields work.

Comment: Oh my God :( I couldn't explain my problem.

i know how boolean works. When the group is deleted, no return about the group.

Would you try that? after delete a group,  get group list with API using sync_token. You will find that you cannot get information about the group.